# How to activate only options when we use click.group()

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, click, command-line-interface

I'm currently working to create Command line arguments with click. I almost done the research, and everything is working fine. The issue is I want to use the only option while working with the `click.group()` other than sub commands.

Lets say `myCommand --version` this should print my application's version but it's raising error saying `Error: Missing command.`

My code is:

```py
import sys
import os as _os
import click
import logging

from myApp import __version__

@click.group()
@click.option('--version', is_flag=True, help="Displays project version")
@click.pass_context
def cli(context, version: bool):
    if version:
        print(__version__)

@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def init(context):
    click.echo(message="Starting initilization for the project" + str(context.obj))

@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def install(context):
    click.echo(message="Starting installing from the saved data")
```

Here --version is only working when I call the command with option like `cli --version init`, But I want this to be `cli --version` to print the version.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `click.version_option` available as a buillt in, which should do what you wanted.

[Documentation for version option](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.version_option)

However, if you want to roll your own implementation, I think you can try adding `invoke_without_command=True` to your group declaration as such:

```py
@click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
```